# Data transformation for time series

Tags: r, time, time-series

Here is an example of my actual dataset :

```
library("tidyverse")
year <- c(2015,2015,2015,2016,2016,2016,2016)
period <- c("P1","P2","P3","P1","P2","P3","P4")
value <- c(120,130,25,114,236,541,248)
dete <- as.tibble(data.frame(year = year,periode = period, value = value))
```

So, in this dataset we have :
Year... the year,
period, it's like a month (equivalent of 4 weeks out of 12)
value, some value of sales for example

My problem is the following :
I want to have in output a tibble that shows me the maximum (value) of each year like that :

```
result <- as.tibble(data.frame(period = c("P1","P2","P3","P4"), occurence = c(0,1,1,0)))
```

But i also want to add weight to it, in this case, the year 2016 have 4 periods out of 12 (12 months in a year) and 2015 got only 3. the appropriate result would be :

```
result <- as.tibble(data.frame(period = c("P1","P2","P3","P4"), occurence = c(0,3/12,4/12,0)))
```

usually i have 12 periods but sometimes for the last year i have only a part of it available.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly your output,

```
dete %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  mutate(occurence_weighted = n() /12,
         max_occurance = paste0("P", max(as.numeric(gsub("P","",periode)))))
```

would give you

```
 year periode value occurence_weighted max_occurance
  <dbl> <fct>   <dbl>              <dbl> <chr>        
1  2015 P1        120              0.25  P3           
2  2015 P2        130              0.25  P3           
3  2015 P3         25              0.25  P3           
4  2016 P1        114              0.333 P4           
5  2016 P2        236              0.333 P4           
6  2016 P3        541              0.333 P4           
7  2016 P4        248              0.333 P4
```

removing redudant columns will give you:

```
dete %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  mutate(occurence_weighted = n() /12,
         max_occurance = paste0("P", max(as.numeric(gsub("P","",periode))))) %>%
  select(year, occurence_weighted, max_occurance ) %>%
  distinct()

   year occurence_weighted max_occurance
  <dbl>              <dbl> <chr>        
1  2015              0.25  P3           
2  2016              0.333 P4
```

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> I want to have in output a tibble that shows me the maximum (value) of each year...weighted by the number of periods in each year.

So I assume you want this:

```
dete %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  mutate(n=n()) %>%
  summarise(max.value=max(value), weight=mean(n) / 12, 
            occurrence=max.value*weight) %>%
  select(-max.value, -weight) # Optional
```

---

```
# A tibble: 2 x 4
   year max.value weight occurence
  <dbl>     <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>
1  2015       130  0.25       32.5
2  2016       541  0.333     180.
```

I don't udnerstand why you have period in the output when you mentioned you wanted by year.

Comment: i was wrong, i want a tibble that shows me for each period the number of times it appears to be the maximum. imagine i have a dataset with 8 years and values in P2 was the maximum 8 times  i want to have in front of P2 -> 8.   the problem is : if the 8th value is on a year with only 6 periods i don't want 8 but 7.5